# How could Hanuman fly to Lanka and expand his size when his bones would have snapped under his weight?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

How could Hanuman increase his size when according to square-cube principle his bones would simply have snapped under his weight?

Comment: Volume includes surface area as well. The same object is increasing. It’s not water contained in a flask both increasing at different rates. Also A particular increase in surface area causes a disproportionate increase in volume in terms of numbers, but that increase in volume is facilitated only because the surface area increased. Not two separate objects

Comment: Ah. Thank you for your explanation. The reason for asking this question is that I saw a quora answer about this saying that Hanuman's bones would have just snapped under his weight.

Comment: Hehe. Quora is not the perfect source for things. People can write anything without a quality check.

Comment: True, true...But there are many claims which I cannot find an answer to from my knowledge which makes me wonder if those claims are actually true or not, so I ask questions on this website to see if anyone has a response to them (because this site has many knowledgeable people there who know more about Hindu scriptures than I do.)

Comment: Hanumān possessed mastery over the aṣṭasiddhis, one of these siddhis is mahimā, via which one can become as big as one wants. Expanding in size, means expanding of the entire body, in the right proportions, in this case. His bones would also develop in that manner, so that they are able to sustain the huge body.

Answer (score 1):

Lord Hanuman's origin is the sacred pudding of King Dashrath, a piece of which was snatched by a kite, and carried to Anjani by Vayu.
It is evident that he was to be a divine being.
"
According to Valmiki's Ramayana, one morning in his childhood, Hanuman was hungry and saw the rising red-colored sun. Mistaking it for a ripe fruit, he leapt up to eat it. In one version of the Hindu legend, the king of gods Indra intervened and struck Hanuman with his thunderbolt. It hit Hanuman on his jaw, and he fell to the earth dead with a broken jaw. Hanuman's father Vayu (air) became upset and withdrew all the air on Earth. The lack of air created immense suffering to all living beings. This led Shiva to intervene and resuscitate Hanuman, which in turn prompted Vayu to return to the living beings. As the mistake was done by the god Indra, he grants Hanuman a wish that his body would be as strong as Indra's Vajra, and that his Vajra can also not harm him. Along with Indra other gods have also granted him wishes: the God Agni granted [Hanuman](https://shyamsangeet.in/hanuman-ji-ke-bhajan-lyrics/) a wish that fire won't harm him; God Varuna granted a wish for Hanuman that water won't harm him; God Vayu granted a wish for Hanuman that he will be as fast as wind and the wind won't harm him. Brahma also granted Hanuman a wish that he can move to any place where he cannot be stopped. Hence these wishes make Hanuman an immortal, who has unique powers and strength."

Thus he was blessed with enormous strength and power. His was the ability to grow to any size and fly. Obviously the Gods would have granted the inner strength to sustain that structure.